# Magento doesn't send autogenerated password

Tags: magento-1.7, email

I've noticed that when I clic on "send auto-generated password" to a customer it sends an email but it doesn't displays the new password, it appears like:

> Dear customer,
>
> Your new password is:

And doesn't displays the password, is in blank. Anyone knows why this can happen?

In the backend/System/transactional emails I have this:

```
<p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 8px 0;"><strong>Your new password is:</strong> {{htmlescape var=$password}}</p>
```

instead of the password (Is the code OK?).

My magento version is 1.7.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password section in the template should look like this:

```
<p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 8px 0;"><strong>Your new password is:</strong> {{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}</p>
```

Comment: Yes! Was that! I put var=$cusomer.password instead of var=$password and now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure with which version the process was changed against a secure url to not send the password via email.
But 1.7 sends a password link instead of a plaintext password

Check against the template of the 1.7.0: https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/7aa9a6fce611cfaf79b9c8f1934942f58ce4f7c6/app/locale/en_US/template/email/account_password_reset_confirmation.html

Comment: I've changed the var=$password to var=$customer.password and works, thanks anyway !! :)

Comment: You should change this. Sending plain text passwords via mail is a security issue.

Comment: Yes you're right. I'll change that too. Thanks!